# Is there any value to using Deja Dup in addition to Ubuntu One file sync?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, deja-dup

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 64bit and am currently using Ubuntu One file sync for all of my files and devices. I just discovered Deja Dup and was wondering if it was a good idea to use it in addition to Ubuntu One?

Comment: Been playing with it since I asked the question, 'freaking awesome program' I'm glad their including it in 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu-One is an excellent tool to synchronise files and folders between multiple machines using the "ubuntu" cloud as storage.  Synchronisation is done automatically when it detects a file change.

However, Deja-Dup is another versatile tool in that you can backup & restore folders to local storage, a local network machine, a remote machine or indeed to a Rackspace or Amazon Cloud - and can be done on a timed-schedule.

I use both Ubuntu-One and Deja-Dup to provide backups - Ubuntu-One to allow me to sync files across multiple computers in real-time and Deja-Dup to backup Ubuntu-One files on a timed-schedule.

The reason I do this is the small-print in the Ubuntu-One terms & conditions - you are responsible for backups of files in the UbuntuOne Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization and backups are two subtly different things.

Ubuntu One will give you immediate access to the current version of your data and no access to older versions of your data.

Déjà Dup will give you slow access to older versions of your data.

So, Ubuntu One will help for some sorts of disaster recovery, namely losing your laptop or some such.

But Déjà Dup will help a few more types of disasters, like, "I need the version of this presentation from last month."  Or "Oh crap, I just copied over this file accidentally and Ubuntu One already synchronized it."